# Obtener la información de un elemento html en PHP

Tags: php, html, bootstrap

Tengo un elemento html con bootstrap (no conozco el nombre) pero es una lista ya establecida:

```
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <select class="form-control" name="proyect-categorie" id="proyect-categorie">
                <option value="">Selecciona una categoría</option>
                <option value="">Activo</option>
                <option value="">Pausado</option>
                <option value="">Cancelado</option>
                <option value="">Concluido</option>
                </select>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Ahora tengo este código php en el que intento mediante `POST` obtener el valor del elemento en una variable llamada `$p_categ`:

```
$p_categ   = $_POST['proyect-categorie'];
```

Para luego asignarle un valor a otra variable llamada `$p_state` dependiendo del valor de la primera:

```
if($p_categ == "Activo"){
    $p_state   = "1";
   } else if($p_categ == "Pausado") {
    $p_state   = "2";
  }else if($p_categ == "Cancelado") {
    $p_state   = "3";
  }else if($p_categ == "Concluido") {
    $p_state   = "0";
  }else{
    $p_state   = "5";
  }
```

Y luego mandarla como valor a una base de datos:

```
   $query   = "UPDATE proyects SET ";
   $query  .= "name ='{$p_name}', state ='{$p_state}', description ='{$p_des}'";
   $query  .=" WHERE id ='{$proyect['id']}'";
```

El problema está en que me manda un error, que se soluciona si a `$p_state` le asigno un valor directamente, pero si no lo hago (que se debe escoger una de las 4 opciones), ese error no se quita.

Cabe destacar que tengo cajas de texto que funcionan bien, sin el elemento que me da problemas, se insertan como debe ser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En el `<select>` no estas pasando ningún valor. Todos los `value` están sin contenido.
Debes colocar el valor de cada `option`.

```
<select class="form-control" name="proyect-categorie" id="proyect-categorie">
     <option value="">Selecciona una categoría</option>
     <option value="Activo">Activo</option>
     <option value="Pausado">Pausado</option>
     <option value="Cancelado">Cancelado</option>
     <option value="Concluido">Concluido</option>
</select>
```

Aunque yo optaría por enviar un número en lugar de una cadena de texto.

```
<select class="form-control" name="proyect-categorie" id="proyect-categorie">
         <option value="">Selecciona una categoría</option>
         <option value="1">Activo</option>
         <option value="2">Pausado</option>
         <option value="3">Cancelado</option>
         <option value="4">Concluido</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: Gracias!!! Efectivamente, eso era